# Is there a software that tells the number of possible flows when "inputing" an workflow?

Tags: selenium, java, test-automation-framework, specflow

I'm making a project that needs to break some big workflows into pieces and I need to know how many possible flows does the Workflow (that I have "inputed") before has.

Does anyone know any software that can tell me that?

Comment: Unless it's severely limited (it's not possible to go back, there are very few decision branches, etc.) the answer to the question of how many possible paths exist through a workflow is "an infinite number". Software to analyze workflows would probably consider back/forward loops as a single piece no matter how many times they were called even though multiple back/forward actions could expose a memory leak.

Comment: Yep.. It makes some sense! Thanks for answering!

Comment: Workflow is a directed graph. For simplicity you can assume it is acyclic, so enumerating all possible test paths is like generating all paths in DAG: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/105330/generation-of-all-path-in-a-directed-acyclic-graph. Obviously, like Kate Paulk said, real workflow may contain cycles, but again, you can found on only certain nodes/edges in a graph, limit number of cycles to 1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the technical answer to your question is no, there are some methods which help you limit the number of scenarios you need to cover to provide suitable coverage.

I particularly like the [Pairwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison) methodology

Luckily there is a (no longer free) tool called [Hexawise](https://hexawise.com/) that helps you make sense of it without a mathematics degree!

A particularly simple example is testing Credit Cards.  This method will help you formulate the minimum numbers of tests to test each variation of card available.

Comment: Can u send me a message so we can discuss a bit? Thanks!

Comment: feel free, or better yet, if you have a general question add a new one onto stack and maybe the discussion will prove helpful to others too :)